# AngularJS: Use variable inside component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I want to use an input variable and display it inside my component HTML but I can't get it to work.

I'm pretty sure I miss something important here but can't say what.

Here is my component declaration:

```
app.component('requestSummary', {
    templateUrl: "./Template/request-summary",
    controller: function RequestSummary() {
        var vm = this;
    },
    bindings: {
        request: "="
    }
});
```

The component template:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ vm.request.Pnr }}</h1>
</div>
```

(I have also tried without the `vm`)

The component use:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="request in vm.requests">
    <md-card-content>
        <request-summary request="request"></request-summary>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

When I do a `console.log(vm)` inside the component controller, I can see my request is there:

[image]

But I don't know how to print it inside the HTML.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components have an automatic default controllerAs controller with an alias of $ctrl. You need to use:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ $ctrl.request.Pnr }}</h1>
</div>
```

And you can get rid of the `var vm = this;`.